# Magento 1.9 remove time from order confirmation

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, date

In my order confirmation, I have this code

```
echo Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($_order->getData('created_at'),Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_MEDIUM, true);
```

and the output is 
**Order date: 16/03/2017 12.27.21**

How do I remove the time from this output? So the correct output I want is
 **Order date: 16/03/2017**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass last parameter as false

```
echo Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($_order->getData('created_at'),Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_MEDIUM, true);
```

if you will see function definition then it will be more clear for you. Here it is

in file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php line number approx 164

```
public function formatDate($date = null, $format = Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT, $showTime = false)
{
}
```

Hope it helps !!
Thanks.